# Method is tail recursive when defined on object but not on class

Tags: scala, recursion

Defining a recursive method on an object:

```
object Recursive {
    def recurse(maxDepth: Int = 10): Unit = {
        if (maxDepth == 0) throw new Exception
        recurse(maxDepth - 1)
    }
}
```

gives:

```
scala> Recursive.recurse(10)
java.lang.Exception
        at Recursive$.recurse(<console>:7)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at RequestResult$.<init>(<console>:9)
        at RequestResult$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at RequestResult$scala_repl_result(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(Interpreter.scala:988)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(Interpreter.scala:988)
        at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scal...
```

But defining it on a class:

```
class Recursive {
    def recurse(maxDepth: Int = 10): Unit = {
        if (maxDepth == 0) throw new Exception
        recurse(maxDepth - 1)
    }
}
```

gives:

```
scala> new Recursive recurse(10)
java.lang.Exception
        at Recursive.recurse(<console>:7)
        at Recursive.recurse(<console>:8)
        at Recursive.recurse(<console>:8)
        at Recursive.recurse(<console>:8)
        at Recursive.recurse(<console>:8)
        at Recursive.recurse(<console>:8)
        at Recursive.recurse(<console>:8)
        at Recursive.recurse(<console>:8)
        at Recursive.recurse(<console>:8)
        at Recursive.recurse(<console>:8)
        at Recursive.recurse(<console>:8)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at RequestResult$.<init>(<console>:9)
        at RequestResult$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at RequestResult$scala_repl_result(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcc..
```

The methods are identical. Why is it not tail recursive when defined on a class?

Comment: always use @tailrec to verify your intention

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want tail-recursion to be performed, `recurse` can not be overridable. If `recurse` is overridable, as in your `class` declaration, any recursion within it has to use dynamic method invocation (because it is potentially polymorphic), which can not be optimized to a goto-style statement.

The `object` singleton declaration statically ensures the unambiguous call to recurse, and lets the compiler proceed with tail recursion optimization.

Answer (score 10):

If you expect a method to be tail recursive, you should annotate it with `@tailrec`. If the compiler can't apply TCO, it will error.

```
scala> import annotation._                           
import annotation._

scala> class Recursive {                                     
     |     @tailrec def recurse(maxDepth: Int = 10): Unit = {
     |         if (maxDepth == 0) throw new Exception        
     |         recurse(maxDepth - 1)                         
     |     }                                                 
     | }
<console>:12: error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method: it is neither private nor final so can be overridden
           @tailrec def recurse(maxDepth: Int = 10): Unit = {
                        ^
```